# perl: split data into columns, choose certain columns, load column 1 as keys to a hash, load column 2 as values in hash

Tags: regex, perl, hash

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# (1) program reads file
# (2) uses the split fxn to split the columns
# (3) loads the IDs that begin with FBgn from the 1st column as keys to a hash
# (4) loads the gene symbol from the second column as the value in each hash entry

my $infile = "fb_synonym_fb_2013_05.tsv";

open( FILE, "<", $infile )
    or die "Cannot open file $!";

my @data = <FILE>;

foreach my $line (@data) {
    my @column = split( /\s+/, $line );
    #print $column[0],"\n";
    my $columnID = $column[0];
        foreach ( my $columnID ) {
            while ( $columnID =~ /(^FBgn\d+)/ ) {
                my $ID = $1;
                print $ID, "\n";
            }
        }
 }
```

I try to run the code but it says that $columnID is an uninitialized value. I'm stuck at this point. I need to select the columns that begin with "FBgn"

input:
data file is very large so here is a selection

```
##primary_FBid current_symbol current_fullname fullname_synonym(s) symbol_synonym(s)
FBtr0000004 Ecol\lacZ[svp-3]RA      lacZ[svp-3]RA
FBtr0000005 Ecol\lacZ[hkb-5953]RA       lacZ[5953]RA,lacZ[hkb-5953]RA,hkb-  lacZ,5953
FBtr0000007 Mab4A11[+]R2.1          
FBtr0000009 Ecol\lacZ[betaTub56D.AS1]RA lacZ[betaTub56D.AS1]RA
FBtr0000010 Ecol\lacZ[betaTub56D.AS2]RA lacZ[betaTub56D.AS2]RA
FBtr0000011 Ecol\lacZ[betaTub56D.AS3]RA lacZ[betaTub56D.AS3]RA
FBtr0000012 Ecol\lacZ[betaTub56D.NN]RA  lacZ[betaTub56D.NN]RA
FBtr0000013 Ecol\lacZ[betaTub56D.NC]RA  lacZ[betaTub56D.NC]RA
FBtr0000014 Ecol\lacZ[betaTub56D.CP]RA  lacZ[betaTub56D.CP]RA
FBtr0000015 Ecol\lacZ[betaTub56D.ACO]RA lacZ[betaTub56D.ACO]RA
FBtr0000016 Ecol\lacZ[betaTub56D.AC3]RA lacZ[betaTub56D.AC3]RA
```

Comment: `*.tsv` files contain tab-separated values, so consider `split`ting on `\t` and not `\s+`, as some of the values may be split, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pre-define the variables `$columnID` and `$ID` outside the looping to allocate them. You also defined `my $columnID` twice.

Try:

```
my @data = <FILE>;
my @column;
my $columnID;
my $ID;

foreach my $line (@data) {
    @column = split( /\s+/, $line );
    #print $column[0],"\n";
    $columnID = $column[0];
    if ( $columnID =~ /(^FBgn\d+)/ ) {
        $ID = $1;
        print $ID, "\n";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry @bashophil, I'm going to recommend against moving variables to the parent block. `@column, $columnID and $ID` are all line-related and lose meaning outside the foreach loop, so I'd keep the declaration within the foreach loop.

Comment: Thx @Mikko I like the comments you are giving. I am here to learn, too. My posted answer is just the way I was working with data files in Perl until now (except the `my @data = <FILE>` which I never used but I didn't know the difference you are explaining). Thx

Comment: Learning by helping others - that's about as awesome as life gets when you think about it. Such a wonderful platform this StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect a logic problem in this section:

```
my $columnID = $column[0];
foreach ( my $columnID ) {
    while ( $columnID =~ /(^FBgn\d+)/ ) {
        my $ID = $1;
        print $ID, "\n";
    }
}
```

You start by iterating through each line, and splitting that line into columns. So far so good.

Then you take the first column and put that into the scalar `$columnID`. Also fine. Worth checking to see if this is defined (in case you have a blank line).

The problem lies in the next line:

```
foreach ( my $columnID )
```

what exactly are you iterating through? You declare a new variable (a new instance of `$columnID` - which you definitely don't want to do because it will hide what you just set $columnID to above) - but... this line doesn't help you.

Next you have:

```
while ( $columnID =~ /(^FBgn\d+)/ ) {
```

... *another* loop. But you don't need it. You just want to know if this is true or false: better to write:

```
if ( $columnID =~ ... ) {
    # action if true
}
```

---

**Summary**: try rewriting your code as:

```
my @data = <FILE>;

foreach my $line (@data) {
    my @column = split( /\s+/, $line );
    my $columnID = $column[0];
    next if ( ! defined( $columnID ) ); # bad line

    if ( $columnID =~ /(^FBgn\d+)/ ) {
        my $ID = $1;
        print $ID, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: If your file is large (as you mention in the text), you should consider working on it line-by-line instead of reading it to memory all at once. You could use `for my $line (<FILE>) {` to get line-by-line processing.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here's my answer anyway:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
@data = ("FBgn34  2.2  3  xxxx\n","FBgn35 20.2 30 yyyy\n");

my %hash = ();
foreach my $line (@data) {
    my @column = split( /\s+/, $line );
    if ( $column[0] =~ /(^FBgn\d+)/ ) {
        $hash{ $column[0] } = $column[1];
    }
 }
 print Dumper(\%hash);
```

Output:

```
{
    'FBgn35' => '20.2',
    'FBgn34' => '2.2'
};
```